# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'evalID'

Tags: scorm

I'm testing my LMS against SCORM 2004 3rd Edition.
I'm using LMS Conformance Test and LMS Test Content Package API which I have downloaded them from www.ADLNet.gov.

The following error occurs when I choose Asset Launch Test activity:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'evalID'

The error occurs in the following line in the LMS Test Content Package API:

```
var result = LMSTestSCODriver.evalID( query1 + "!" + query2 );
```

What's the problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully run any other tests? If not, the first thing to check would be that you have the proper Java version installed.

Comment: No. The error occurs in all LMS Test Content Packages exactly in the same line (i.e., var result = LMSTestSCODriver.evalID( query1 + "!" + query2 )). My windows is 7. My browser is Internet Explorer 9. What version of Java should I download and install? Do you have the download link? Thank you.

Comment: I installed all versions of Java but the problem was NOT solved. Please help me.